# Where to get this Java.exe file for a SQL Developer installation

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just installed Oracle 11g, and tried to start Oracle SQL developer so as to start writing queries.

It is asking me:

```
Enter the full pathname for the java.exe file .
```

Where do I find this? I did a global search for `java.exe` and am sure did not get some Oracle related pdf files. Also my Oracle is installed out of users/vas.

Answer (score 59):

I found my java.exe that worked for SQL Developer at C:\ORACLE11G\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdk\bin where C:\ORACLE11G is my Oracle Home. The client that I have installed is 11.2.0.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, your advice helped me, even without any additional installations, having only oracle client.

Comment: Thank you. On my machine the path was C:\oracle\product\11.2.0.2\client_1\jdk\bin\java.exe

Comment: OMG, I love these Java-based products: the installer installs JDK, but the app still "does not know" the path to it. [sarcasm] I have heard rumors Oracle is "a leading DBMS" on the planet? Outdated GUI and half-working setup that's what it takes to be a leader? [/sarcasm]

Comment: FWIW I had a similar location when installing Personal Edition of 12.1: C:\ORACLE_HOME\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdk\bin where ORACLE_HOME is the Oracle home.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had the same issue. The JDK under oracle product is 1.5.0_17. May be that is the JDK required to run SQL developer. Just my speculation.

Comment: @Moiz..worked like a charm . I never knew , jdk would get auto installed along with the sql developer.Thanks for pointing it out. +1 for this

Answer (score 37):

I encountered the following message repeatedly when trying to start SQL Developer from my installation of Oracle Database 11g Enterprise: Enter the full pathname for java.exe.

No matter how many times I browsed to the correct path, I kept being presented with the exact same dialog box. This was in Windows 7, and the solution was to right-click on the SQL Developer icon and select "**Run as administrator**". I then used this path: C:\app\shellperson\product\11.1.0\db_1\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe

Comment: Thanks!  This same logic applies to Win10.

Answer (score 11):

You need to install JAVA SDK 
and give the path upto bin directory which contains the java.exe file.

example - c:/programfiles/java/jdk/bin

Answer (score 10):

Hhere is what what I did to fix it:

**Prerequisite**

- Make sure JDK is installed (Not JRE).
- Make sure Oracle is installed

**After**

1. Open the file `..\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldevloper.conf` and add the following line to set jdk path:

   `SetJavaHome C:\Program Files\Oracle\11g\product\11.1.0\client_1\jdk`

   If it dont allow you to save the file, copy whole sqldeveloper folder to a different location where you have write access to modify this file.
2. Run `sqldeveloper.exe` (from the new place if you moved the folder out from oracle folders) as administrator and enter the jdk path that comes with your oracle installation: e.g. `C:\Program Files\Oracle\11g\product\11.1.0\client_1\jdk\bin`

Answer (score 5):

You have to give the path to jdk ...typically C:\Program Files\Java..
Still if it is asking you for the path then 
Check this http://www.shellperson.net/oracle-sql-developer-enter-the-full-pathname-for-java-exe/

Answer (score 4):

[Context]
**In a virtual machine of WinXP**.

My **"java.exe"** was in the Oracle11g folder, under the path **"C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk\bin\java.exe"**.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Please provide full path >

In mines case it was E:\app\ankitmittal01\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk\bin\java.exe

From : http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/07/oracle-11g-and-sql-developer.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have Java installed, java.exe will be in the bin directory.  If you can't find it, download and install Java, then use the install path + "\bin".

Comment: thanks for the quick answer . what is the connection betweeen oracle SQL and java?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to install Java or you just want to get started writing queries quickly, then use SQL*Plus, which is the command line too.

It's not pretty, but will get you started quickly and there is Oracle documentation on it.

Comment: Often I think sticking a fork in my eye would be better than using SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 2):

you can enter the jdk path required as th full path for java.exe in sql developer for oracle 11g.

I found the jdk at the following path in my system.

c:\app\sony\product\11.0.0\db_1\jdk

Answer (score 1):

Use any JDK installation as long as it is NOT 64bit.
The easiest way to find out if it is 64bit installation is to check the folder it resides into.
e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\... is for 64 bit programs
C:\Program Files (x86)\... is for 32 bit programs
```

Answer (score 0):

You must install the latest Java SE Development Kit (note not the Java SE Runtime Environment ) and provide the path ex C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41

Answer (score 0):

you should browse to where java installed, then go to bin directory which contains the java.exe file.

example - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\bin\java.exe

but you should run your SQL Developer as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you are asked to enter the full pathname for the JDK, click Browse and find it. For example, on a Windows system the path might have a name similar to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51.