# sql developer, strange error while

Tags: installation, oracle-sqldeveloper

After installing Oracle Db, Sql developer is asking "Enter the full pathname for java.exe" .
I have installed java deveopment kit, so I browse for java exe file in  jdk1.8.0_151 /bin. After clicking ok, the same widnow with the same msg is still there ("Enter the full pathname for java.exe"), does anybody know how to fix that?
I have tried to reinstall , but nothing changed. 
TY

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665043/where-to-get-this-java-exe-file-for-a-sql-developer-installation

Comment: You need to provide more info re your environment ... and it looks like this question may already have been answered elsewhere, raising as duplicate unless further information is provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to get this Java.exe file for a SQL Developer installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665043/where-to-get-this-java-exe-file-for-a-sql-developer-installation)

Comment: you never said which exact version of sqldev you downloaded. older versions wanted the /bin directory, others just wanted the jdk home directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider downloading [Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) so that you wouldn't need to worry about JDK? Installation notes say:

> This archive includes both SQL Developer and an embedded copy of the Java 8 Development Kit (JDK). Simply extract the zip to a fresh directory and run the sqldeveloper.exe in the top directory. The EXE is configured to run the embedded JDK by default.

More info [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-windows-1969674.html).

Comment: Yap. And only this helped. I've tried all other paths and solutions, without success. so, thanks much.